# PayPal send money from merchant to user with REST API

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I can't find the option to send money to users through the REST API. I see only sale intent...
Is it possible? Or do I need the classic API?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality to send payments implicitly from your account is not yet supported with the RESTful APIs.